# What use instead of deprecated android.preference library on android 10+?

Tags: android, android-preferences, androidx

I start new tv app and now I need to develop dynamic preferences for set quality of stream, language of stream etc.
So I was planning to use android.preference library and dynamically generate perfs base on stream data. But on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html is

> Note: This guide explains how to use the AndroidX Preference library.
>   Starting with Android 10, the platform android.preference library is
>   deprecated.

But there is no redirection to replacement. So what to use in place of android.preference library?

Also on that guide is also note:

> Note: This guide assumes you are using
>   **androidx.preference:preference**:1.1.0-alpha04 or higher. Some features
>   might be unavailable on older versions of the library.

so `androidx.preference:preference` will be deprecated.

Answer (score 8):

> the platform android.preference library is deprecated. But there is no redirection to replacement.

You can check in [Android 10 documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-all#preferences):
*The android.preference library is deprecated as of Android 10*. Developers **should instead use the AndroidX preference library**, part of Android Jetpack.

The replacement is the [**androidx-preference**](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/package-summary) library.
Just use:

```
dependencies {
    def preference_version = "1.1.0"

    // Java
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:$preference_version"
    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:$preference_version"
}
```

More info about the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/preference).

Also:

> Note: This guide assumes you are using androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0-alpha04 or higher. Some features might be unavailable on older versions of the library.

[It means](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/versions/) that while a release is in alpha, APIs may be added, removed, or changed.

Comment: it seems that what you pointed will be deprecated. See updated question.

Comment: @LunaVulpo There is a misunderstanding. Androidx-preference library is quite new and it will replace the android preference. You can check the documentation of the *old* [android.preference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/package-summary) platform. **These classes are deprecated. Use the AndroidX Preference Library for consistent behavior across all devices.** Also the stable version 1.1.0 was released a [few days ago](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/preference#1.1.0)

Comment: Also you can check this link in Android 10 [changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-all#preferences). I've just updated the answer.

Comment: The AndroidX variant won't be deprecated at this time, most likely.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the steps (based on @GabrieleMariotti's helpful answer) to upgrade to use the AndroidX Preference library:

- To your `build.gradle (Module:app)` add the following to `dependencies`

  ```
  dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
  implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0"
  ...
  }
  ```
- I also kept the `xmlns:android` url in res/xml/my_preferences.xml, despite the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings#create_a_hierarchy) suggesting otherwise. That is, I have

  ```
  <PreferenceScreen
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

      <PreferenceCategory android:title="Individual">
          <Preference
              android:key="preference_play_activity"
              android:title="Play Activity">
              <intent
                  android:targetClass="com.myorg.mythirdapp.PlayActivity"
                  android:targetPackage="com.myorg.mythirdapp" />
          </Preference>
          ...
  ```

  ... rather than ...

  ```
  <PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
  ```